# How to find a solution of a second order differential equation with constant RHS?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This may be a really dumb question but I've never come across this problem before, until now. I have a differential equation with constant right-hand side:

$$y''+ 4y = 5.$$
Normally I would find out the homogeneous solution which would be: $$y=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t).$$

But now I am stuck. I need to find the particular solution. Should/can that be just a constant? Or is it zero? Or five? If so why?

I really don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*But now I am stuck. I need to find the particular solution. Should/can that be just a constant? Or is it zero? Or five? If so why?*

You can answer your questions easily just try.

$$y_p''+4y_p=5$$

If you try $y_p=0$ you have:
$$(0)''+4\times 0=5$$
$$0\ne 5$$
So it's not correct.
If you try $y_p=5$ then:
$$(5)''+4 \times 5 =5$$
$$20 \ne 5$$
So it's not correct. Try a constant $y_p=A$
$$(A)''+4A=5$$
$$4A=5 \implies A=\dfrac 54$$